# PhpMyAdmin username password

Tags: drupal, phpmyadmin

I've been lumped with a drupal site circa 2008.

Can someone point me to the file where I might look to find the PhpMyAdmin login credentials?

Answer (score 3):

```
DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/default/settings.php
```

Search for a variable like this:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'DATABASE',
      'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
      'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
      'host' => 'HOST',
      'port' => 'PORT',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => 'PREFIX_',
    ),
  ),
);
```